# How to do fit image in UITextview used by NSAttributedString get from HTML data in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios10

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[HTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
_textView.attributedText=attributedString;
```

In this screen shot image is not fit to screen. it's cut:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change size of NSTextAttachment Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945236/change-size-of-nstextattachment-image)

Comment: I have same issue, is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

you must to declare size of NSTextAttachment, which you want to set to attributedString;

For example:

```
            NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
            textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:kSmallPencilName];
            textAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, (field.size.height * 9) * 0.75 / 15, field.size.height * 0.75 ); // image 9x15
            NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
```

If you have instance of NSAttributedString you can get a UIImage like here:

```
[attrStringWithImage enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName
                        inRange:NSMakeRange(0, textStorage.length)
                        options:0
                     usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
 {
     NSTextAttachment* attachment = (NSTextAttachment*)value;
     NSFileWrapper* attachmentWrapper = attachment.fileWrapper;
     [attachmentWrapper writeToURL:outputURL options:NSFileWrapperWritingAtomic originalContentsURL:nil error:nil];
 }
```

Comment: i get attributedString from Html Data so how can do this?

Comment: I answered above. God luck!